# Dynamic image ids cannot be referenced by JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

On my website I have a navigation list with images representing the navigation links, I have written a `onmouseover` JavaScript function which changes the imgsrc to a darker version of the image.

I now recognized that if there are more than one list elements in the navigation (the number of list elements in the navigation is dynamic) the JavaScript function doesn't work. For one element it does work though.

Now I found the error: Since the image is created in a while function it always has the same id, so if there are more then one navigation elements it has multiple images called with the same id, so of course the JavaScript function cannot refer them.

Strangely enough I find it quite hard to solve the problem. Can someone tell me please why the following approach wont work?

```
<html>
<head>
<script
language="JavaScript">
function over(source,c) {
  c.src = "Images/List/streams/"+source+"_mo.png";
}
function out(source,c) {
  c.src = "Images/List/streams/"+source+".png";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
...
while($row_player = mysql_fetch_object($players)) {
    $image   = 'pic'.$row_player->Id;
    echo "<a href=".$row_player->Page." target=_parent
    onmouseover= over(".$row_player->Id,$image.")
    onmouseout = out(".$row_player->Id,$image.")> 
    <li>
    <img id=".$image." src=Images/List/streams/".$row_player->Id.".png>
    </li>
    </a>";  
}
...
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

This is the code I first used, which works only for one element:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
language="JavaScript">
function over(source) {
    pic.src = "Images/List/streams/"+source+"_mo.png";
}
function out(source) {
    pic.src = "Images/List/streams/"+source+".png";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
...
while($row_player = mysql_fetch_object($players)) {
        echo "<a href=".$row_player->Page." target=_parent
        onmouseover= over(".$row_player->Id.")
        onmouseout = out(".$row_player->Id.")> 
        <li>
        <img id=pic src=Images/List/streams/".$row_player->Id.".png>
        </li>
        </a>";  
}
...
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

By the way the while loops are all in an echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code. One is that in your `over` and `out` functions, `c` is a string (the ID of the element) but you are treating it as if it is an element. Use `document.getElementById(c).src = ...` instead of `c.src = ...`.

Another problem is that you are incorrectly echoing the arguments to `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. You need to separate them with a comma and quote them. Instead of `onmouseover= over(".$row_player->Id,$image.")`, use

```
onmouseover=\"over(\"".$row_player->Id."\", \"".$image."\")\"
```

and same for `onmouseout`. Quoting HTML attributes allows you to include spaces in their values (and makes it so that your markup will validate). You need to quote the arguments to the Javascript function because otherwise Javascript will thing the image ID is the name of a variable, not a string.

Comment: Hey Emily, thank you for your answer.
I already found the error with the "," reviewing the code, but i didnt know about the document.getElementById thing. I tried it out, sadly it still won`t work. By the way call has to be this way over(".$row_player->Id.",".$image.") with the blank between , and " it strangly completly breaks the quotations.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. What do you mean by breaks the quotations? In any case, it would be helpful to see any error messages you're getting from PHP or on the Javascript console.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's because if you have a space in your HTML attribute the page won't parse without quotations. You should be quoting all your HTML attributes. You also need to quote the strings that you're passing as arguments to Javascript, so for example, `onmouseover=\"over(\"".$row_player->Id."\", \"".$image."\")\"`. If it still doesn't work after you do that, then please include the error messages you're getting. I'll update the answer to include these things.

Comment: It works.
I rly dont know why but if i write it this way it works xD
document.getElementById('pic'+source). Thx for your help though